# simplifying java array layout

Tags: java, arrays, processing

is there any other way of applying this table to array rather than creating 31 of them?

The layout looks like:

state_name|year|crimetype1|crimetype2|place|count|

---

row1: state1|2001|murder|knife|home|5|

row2: state1|2001|murder|axe|home|2|

row3: state2|2001|robbery|baseball|shop|1|

and so on for 31 different states.

I thought of creating 31 arrays for each state with 5 rows but is there any other way of making it simpler?

Comment: Why not create a class `State`, and add the data per year to it? Think in OO, not primitives. Model the domain, then apply the solution.

Comment: I would suggest to create a class. That class would then have all the necessary data as a state. Then you just create a new instances for all the items. You can also take advantage of overriding the `toString()` method if you want to display each row like you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: objects. That way, you will not have to have nested arrays.

Make a class:

```
public class Crime{
    private int year;
    private String state;
    private String crimeType1, crimeType2;
    private String place;
    private int count;

    //And then you'd have some useful stuff here...
}
```

Besides this, I don't think you should combine the 31 values anymore - they are 31 separate, independent occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `Crime` object which can represent a single row in that collection.  Let's make it naturally comparable against itself based on the state.

```
public class Crime implements Comparable<Crime> {
    private String state;
    private Year year;
    private String crimeType1;
    private String crimeType2;
    private String place;
    private int count;

    public int compareTo(Crime other) {
        return state.compareTo(other.state);
    }
}
```

I leave the construction of this object as an exercise for the reader.

Next, you'll want to add the results of that value to a list.

```
List<Crime> crimes = new ArrayList<>();

// In a loop reading the file
    crimes.add(crime);
```

At this point your work is pretty much done; if you want to get the crimes by a specific state, you can use the Stream API to filter based on that.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create class Crime as follows 
getHeader() returns header and getRow will return the row . (or toString)

```
public class Crime {

    String stateName;
    String year;
    //...

    public static String getHeader(){
        //you can improve this
        return "state_name|year|crimetype1|crimetype2|place|count|";
    }

    public String getRow(){        
        return stateName + "|" + year +"|" ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Crime> state  = new ArrayList<>(31);
        //or 
        List<Crime> state = Arrays.asList(new Crime[] {
           new Crime("ST","2004",..),... 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as KevinO pointed if you are coding OO language it is good to think in OO way otherwise there no point of using `java`.

Create a `Crime` class with all the values except state and then a Map

`Map<String,ArrayList<Crime>> multiMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Crime>>();`

Here `String` is state name and the `ArrayList` for all the crimes in that state, So at the end there will be 31 keys (Here we are using state as unique keys) in muliMap `Object`.

So later you no need to filter statewise crimes, all you need to do is

```
ArrayList<Crime> state1Crimes = multiMap.get("state1");
```

Simple and straight forward.